# TypeError: a float is required -- when using pow() and math.sqrt()

Tags: python

I keep getting this error message when i try to use my quadratic formula program:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\i=1000000000000.py", line 6, in <module>
    d = (pow(b,2)-4*a*c)
TypeError: a float is required
```

What is actually wrong here and what can be done to fix it?

Heres the actual code

```
import math
print("this is a quadratic formula application.")
a = input("Enter 'a' value: ")
b = input("Enter 'b' value: ")
c = input("Enter 'c' value: ")
d = (pow(b,2)-4*a*c)

if d < 0:
    print("there is no answer")
elif d == 0:
    print("There is only one answer: ",x)
    x =( -b + (d))/ (2*a)
else:
    print(" There are two answers: ",x1,"and ",x2)
    x1 =( -b + (sqrt(d,2)))/ (2*a)
    x2 =( -b - (sqrt(d,2)))/ (2*a)
```

Comment: A float is required, and you don't have one, because `input` returns a string in Python 3. Call `float` on the strings the user inputs to gets floats.

Comment: Thank you for your help! I was able to get it working:)

Answer (score 0):

[`input`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#input) returns a string object in Python 3.x.  You need to explicitly convert this into a number object:

```
a = float(input("Enter 'a' value: "))
b = float(input("Enter 'b' value: "))
c = float(input("Enter 'c' value: "))
```

Otherwise, you will be giving a string to `math.pow`:

```
>>> import math
>>>
>>> a = input("Enter 'a' value: ")
Enter 'a' value: 2
>>> math.pow(a, 2)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: a float is required
>>>
>>> a = float(input("Enter 'a' value: "))
Enter 'a' value: 2
>>> math.pow(a, 2)
4.0
>>>
```